# How to change audio track in played movie which is streamed to Apple TV via VLC local sharing?

Tags: vlc, tvos

I setup the VLC app on Apple TV following [this](https://www.cultofmac.com/406734/how-to-use-vlc-to-watch-any-video-on-apple-tv/) tutorial and I can stream movies from my Macbook Pro to Apple TV. The only thing I don't know how to change is audio track. The movies has multiple audio tracks and it seems VLC can play only the default.

How can I change the audio track in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it. One have to swipe down on Apple TV's remote and the menu for audio tracks and subtitles will appear.